# biblatex-chicago: Separator between citations

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

I am using the `biblatex-chicago` package for writing a paper for a journal, that requires footnote citations:

```
\usepackage[notes,natbib,isbn=false,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
```

However, I have a problem when it comes to citing two (or more) sources and adding some comments to them. For example, in this case:

```
\footcites[A argues 123. See][]{Zambernardi2011}[However, B believes 456. See][]{See2001}
```

the output looks like this:

```
A argues 123. See A, Titel, Journal, Year; However, B believes 456. See B, Titel, Journal Year.
```

What I need is a different separator after the citation of A2003. I do not want to have a semicolon, but a period!

```
@article{Zambernardi2011,
    Author = {Zambernardi, Lorenzo},
    Date-Added = {2017-04-20 12:58:28 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2017-04-20 12:59:41 +0000},
    Journal = {Review of International Studies},
    Number = {3},
    Pages = {1335-1356},
    Title = {The impotence of power: Morgenthau's critique of American intervention in Vietnam},
    Volume = {37},
    Year = {2011}}

@article{See2001,
    Author = {See, Jennifer W.},
    Date-Added = {2017-04-20 12:57:29 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2017-04-20 12:58:22 +0000},
    Journal = {Pacific Historical Review},
    Number = {3},
    Pages = {419-447},
    Title = {A Prophet Without Honor: Hans Morgenthau and the War in Vietnam, 1955-1965},
    Volume = {70},
    Year = {2001}}
```

Comment: Why not just use a `\footnote` command? I don't really see what you gain from using a complicated long `\footcites` command. You can do this: `\footnote{\citeauthor{A2003} argues 123. See \cite{A2003}. However, \citeauthor{B2009} believes 456. See \cite{B2009}.}`

Comment: Because I need a certain citation style (Chicago Style) that is not possible with the \footnote and  and \cite commands.

Comment: How is the `\footnote` method I gave different to what you want?

Comment: I need the full citation in the Footnote when citing a book/article for the first time, then I need a short version of this citation. I cannot do that with \cite. But \footcite in the biblatex-chicago package does that for me.

Comment: Hmm. I must be missing something. I *do* get long and short citations using `\cite` in `\footnote`.  The `biblatex` cite tracker doesn't care what citation command you use. It knows whether you have cited it more than once or not.

Comment: Can you expand question to include a proper MWE that I can work from?

Comment: Do you have now all the relevant information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not quite sure why you wouldn't see long and short citations with `\cite`, but does this give the output you want? I think it's more readable than using `\footcites`. And it does give you the period where you want it. (Note that this is @moewe's alternative answer above, but presented with code and output).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[notes,natbib,isbn=false,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}  
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Zambernardi2011,
  Author = {Zambernardi, Lorenzo},
  Date-Added = {2017-04-20 12:58:28 +0000},
  Date-Modified = {2017-04-20 12:59:41 +0000},
  Journal = {Review of International Studies},
  Number = {3},
  Pages = {1335-1356},
  Title = {The impotence of power: Morgenthau's critique of American intervention in Vietnam},
  Volume = {37},
  Year = {2011}
}
@article{See2001,
  Author = {See, Jennifer W.},
  Date-Added = {2017-04-20 12:57:29 +0000},
  Date-Modified = {2017-04-20 12:58:22 +0000},
  Journal = {Pacific Historical Review},
  Number = {3},
  Pages = {419-447},
  Title = {A Prophet Without Honor: Hans Morgenthau and the War in Vietnam, 1955--1965},
  Volume = {70},
  Year = {2001}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
First Citation.\footnote{\citeauthor{Zambernardi2011} argues 123. See
\cite{Zambernardi2011}. However, \citeauthor{See2001} believes 456. See
\cite{See2001}.}

Subsequent citation.\footnote{\citeauthor{Zambernardi2011} argues 123. See
\cite{Zambernardi2011}. However, \citeauthor{See2001} believes 456. See
\cite{See2001}.}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The separator between to citations is called `\multicitedelim`, you can redefine it to be a full stop with

```
\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addperiod\space}
```

---

Since `\multicitedelim` is not set with `\setunit` but directly, it is hard to correct a wrong delimiter choice later on. Since the delimiter is set at a point where we can't know if the next citation has a pre-note we can't condition on that easily either.

So at the moment you can either manually switch `\multicitedelim` to `\addperiod\space` locally with

```
\AtNextCite{\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addperiod\space}}
```

before citations where you need a full stop.

Or you use `\footnote` directly. If your text is longer that becomes a very attractive option.

```
\footnote{A argues 123. \cite[See][]{sigfridsson}. However, B believes 456. \[See][]cite{worman}}
```

The pre-note argument is quite well-suited for short introductory 'remarks' like 'cf.', 'see', but not so much for longer discussions.

Comment: Thank you! That almost solves my problem. Because now, multiple citations are also separated by a space and period. In these cases, the semicolon would be perfect. So is there a way to get both?

Comment: @feder80 When do you want to use a period and when do you want a semicolon? Is there some reliable 'algorithm' to determine that?

Comment: Yes, there is! I need a period between the end of a citation and the beginning of a text, for example: Citation #period# Text. But I need a semicolon between multiple citations: Citation #semicolon# Citation #period# Text.